# Restcomm iOS issue, dependency incompatibility with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, restcomm

I have an iOS project written purely in Swift which uses CocoaPods for dependency management. In my Podfile I have the "use_frameworks!" keyword to inform CocoaPods that I want my dependencies as Swift dynamic frameworks.

Trying to integrate the Restcomm iOS SDK (which is written in ObjC) into my project, I have run into the following issue:
After adding the pod to my podfile and doing a "pod install", the workspace is updated and the pod is installed just fine. Although, the build fails with an error: Lexical or preprocessor issue: sofia-sip/sdp.h file not found. The sofia-sip-library is a dependency of the restcomm-ios-sdk itself.

For reference, I also created a new iOS project, now in ObjC, and installed the restcomm-ios-sdk without using frameworks. After that, the build runs just fine.

Seems like the issue is related to my project being in Swift and using dynamic frameworks, while the restcomm sdk is a static ObjC library.
I have tried to modify the Target / Build Settings / Header Search Paths, but it turns out using dynamic frameworks leaves my Pods/Headers folder empty.

Others have run into similar issues before:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5330, https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4605, https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3839

Although, none of these threads offer a solution that would work for me. Any idea how I could go about solving the issue?

Comment: I'm afraid that unless CocoaPods provide a way to handle this scenario, there is no way around this :(. It's too bad that there is no truly universal dependency management for iOS.